# Send file as a response from ajax request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a javascript function that sends the name of the audio file on my server to a php script using jquery get. It looks like this:

```
function getAudioClip() {
    var x = document.getElementById("clips").value;
    $.get( "get_audio.php", { filename: x } )
      .done(function( data ) {
        loadAudioClip(data);
      });
}
```

The function `loadAudioClip(data)` displays the waveform of the audio file given as data. I want to make get_audio.php return the audio file with the file name x, so I can use it to display the waveform using my loadAudioClip(data) function.

**Edit:** I figured out that maybe I can get a file directly instead of using php, like this

```
function getAudioClip() {
    var x = document.getElementById("clips").value;
    $.get( "audio/" + x , function( data ) {
      loadAudioClip(data);
    });
}
```

Is that possible? x is a filename(ex. MyRecording02.wav).

Comment: retrieve a file via AJAX? Something tells me this isn't a good idea...

Comment: @cale_b Well, how should I do this then? I have a list of audio files, and when the user click on a file from the list, I want the waveform to change according to the file selected. For that I have to get a file from the server, right?

Comment: Use `readfile($filename)` in the PHP script.

Comment: If the audio file is under the webroot, the second function should work. Did you try it?

Comment: @Barmar For some reason it doesn't. The audio file is in audio folder that is inside webroot folder. That's why I specify the path to audio/x, x being file name...

Comment: @Barmar It's working now. I passed the wrong filenames.

Answer (score 0):

Opening an audio file with PHP will be slow process. Maybe you can check the existence of the file with PHP, and then if file exists, simply do something like this:

```
header("Location: $filename");
```

Comment: This requires the file to be directly accessible through the webserver.

Comment: @Barmar yes, that's what OP asked for.